# How to write file upload function ajax, jquery, php? How should I write my '.submit()' using Ajax function?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, file-upload

```css
/* -----Progress Bar CSS----- */

#prog-div{
    
    width:100%;
    max-width: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 50px;
    display: none;
}

/* -----Progress Bar----- */
```

```js
//updated ajax with bootstrap progress bar.

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#file-submit").click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var formdata = new FormData($(this).parents('form')[0]);

$.ajax ({
xhr : function(){
$("#prog-div").show();
var xhr =new window.XMLHttpRequest();


xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event){

if(event.lengthComputable){
  var percent = Math.round((event.loaded / event.total)*100);

  $('#progressBar').attr('aria-valuenow', percent).css('width', percent + '%').text(percent + '%');
}

});

return xhr;
},
type: "POST",
url: "upload.php",
dataType : 'json',
data: formdata,
success: function(data){

if(data.status){
alert(data.status);
$( "#file-upload" ).val("");
$("#label-text").text("Select Files to Upload");
$("#prog-div").hide();
}else{
$("#prog-div").hide();
alert(data.error);
//$("#label-text").text("Select Files to Upload");

}
},
processData:false,
contentType: false,
cache: false
});
return false; 
})
});


</script>
```

```html
<!--my html with bootstrap progressbar below the form-->

<!-- Progress Bar -->
<div id ="prog-div">
<div class="progress">
<div id="progressBar" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;">
0%
</div>
</div>
</div>    
<!-- Progress Bar -->
```

I am trying to build a file upload and need to learn  how should I write  my '.submit()' using Ajax function will be really helpful. As i am a newbie.

As i have read that we have to create formdata object and and intiate the xmlhttp request but i dont understand how to use all this ajax thing together. with php for file upload. Please help. thanks.

I have tried this ajax code(see below) and i can sense there is something wrong in it. Please help me correct it.

```js
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

//file upload php code here //

//encode the result in json format
$json = json_encode(array(
'success' => $success,
'error' => $error
));

echo $json;
exit();
}
?>
```

```html
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

                           
<input id="file-upload" type="file" name="fileToUpload[]" multiple required>

<input type="submit" id="file-submit" value="Upload Selected Files">

</form>
```

```js
//My AJAX Code

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#file-submit").click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var formdata = new FormData($(this).parents('form')[0]);

$.ajax ({
type: "POST",
url: "upload.php",
data: formdata,
success: function(data){
    alert("Data uploaded: " +data);
},
processData:false,
contentType: false,
cache: false
});
return false; 

})

});
```

```js
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

//function to get the extension of the file
function getExt($name){
$array = explode(".", $name);
$ext = strtolower(end($array));
return $ext;
}

//create global array
$allowed = array('jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'mp4');
$success = array();
$error = array();

if(isset($_FILES['fileToUpload']) && !empty($_FILES['fileToUpload'])){
foreach ($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'] as $key => $name) {
$tmp = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'][$key];
$ext = getExt($name);
$size = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'][$key];

// check the extension is valid or not
if(in_array($ext, $allowed) == true){
$filename = md5($name) . time() .'.'.$ext;
//check the size of the file
if($size <= 10485760){
if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, 'resources/uploaded_files/'.$filename) === true){
$success[] = array('name' => $name, 'location' => 'resources/uploaded_files/'.$filename);
}else{
$error[] = array('name' => $name, 'msg' => 'File is not uploaded');
}
}else{
$error[] = array('name' => $name, 'msg' => 'File size more than 2MB');
}
}else{
$error[] = array('name' => $name, 'msg' => 'File Type not allowed');
}
}

//encode the result in json format



$json = json_encode(array(
'success' => $success,
'error' => $error
));

echo $jason; die;
exit();
}
?>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<title>Files Upload</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--- Progress Bar Style--->   
<style>
#myBar {
width: 10%;
height: 30px;
background-color: #4CAF50;
text-align: center; /* To center it horizontally  */
line-height: 30px; /* To center it vertically */
color: white;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input id="file-upload" type="file" name="fileToUpload[]" multiple required>
<input type="submit" id="file-submit" value="Upload Selected Files" onclick="move()">
</form>

<!-- Progress Bar -->
<div id="myProgress">
<div id="myBar">0%</div>
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
function move() {
var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
var width = 0;
var id = setInterval(frame, 0);
function frame() {
if (width >= 100) {
    clearInterval(id);
} else {
    width++;
    elem.style.width = width + '%';
    elem.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
}
}
}




$(document).ready(function(){
$("#file-submit").click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var formdata = new FormData($(this).parents('form')[0]);

$.ajax ({
type: "POST",
url: "upload.php",
dataType : 'json',
data: formdata,
success: function(data){

    if(data.status){
        alert(data.status);
    }else{
        alert(data.error);
    }
},
processData:false,
contentType: false,
cache: false
});
return false; 
})
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the below files code to upload the files and return `success` or `error` in the jason format:

**index.php file code**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<title>Files Upload</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input id="file-upload" type="file" name="fileToUpload[]" multiple required>
    <input type="submit" id="file-submit" value="Upload Selected Files">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#file-submit").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var formdata = new FormData($(this).parents('form')[0]);

        $.ajax ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "upload.php",
        dataType : 'json',
        data: formdata,
        success: function(data){

            if(data.status){
                alert(data.status);
            }else{
                alert(data.error);
            }
        },
        processData:false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false
        });
        return false; 
        })
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**upload.php file code here**

```
<?php
    function getExt($name){
    $array = explode(".", $name);
    $ext = strtolower(end($array));
    return $ext;
    }

    //create global array
    $allowed = array('jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'mp4');
    $message = array();
    $error = array();
    $jason = array();

    if(isset($_FILES['fileToUpload']) && !empty($_FILES['fileToUpload'])){
      foreach ($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'] as $key => $name) {
        $tmp = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $ext = getExt($name);
        $size = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'][$key];

        // check the extension is valid or not
        if(in_array($ext, $allowed) == true){
          $filename = md5($name) . time() .'.'.$ext;
        //check the size of the file
        if($size <= 10485760){
          if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, 'uploadFiles/'.$filename) === true){
            $message['status'] = 'File is uploaded successfully';  

          }else{
            $message['error'] = 'File is not uploaded';
          }
        }else{
            $message['error'] = 'File size more than 2MB';
          }
        }else{
          $message['error'] = 'File Type not allowed';
        }
      }

    echo json_encode($message);exit();

    }
?>
```

Hope this help!!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142390/discussion-on-answer-by-magedev0688-how-to-write-file-upload-function-ajax-jque).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution, it support file upload : http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
        $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
            alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
        }); 
    });
```